# Angular 2 and Ionic 3 - TypeError: (...) is not a function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to build an app with a simple click function. I added the handler to the buttons in the users.html page, and the app runs until I arrive at the page where I can click on either of the two handled buttons. When I click on the buttons, I get the error noted below, that it is not a function.

I defined the function onLoadUser() in the users.ts file. The class is exported.

**Technology**

- Ionic 3
- Angular2

**Error**

[image: TypeError: not a function]

**Directory structure**

[image: Directory Structure]

**users.html**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>The Users</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button (click)="onLoadUser('Max')">User 'Max'</button>
  <hr>
  <button ion-button (click)="onLoadUser('Anna')">User 'Anna'</button>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer padding>
  <p>The Footer</p>
</ion-footer>
```

**users.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from "ionic-angular";

import { UserPage } from "./user/user";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-users',
  templateUrl: 'users.html'
})

export class UsersPage {
  constructor (private navCtrl: NavController) {}

  onLoadUser(name: string) {
    this.navCtrl.push(UserPage, {userName: name});
  }
}
```

How can I connect the onLoadUser function to the button click event?

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. You may try rebuilding the project, or clearing the browser cache before running it again.

Comment: I have seen this happen before when something in the Css is actually hiding or disabling the button. May want to double check that. Code looks good to me as well.

Comment: I had similar bugs when using ionic serve command. you just have to save the ts and the html file again and again. or re run ionic serve.

Comment: rerun the serve command

Comment: hmm.. its working in stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-8kyteb?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html is your page configured correctly in app module?

Comment: check your html page , the error is there

Comment: @KevinRED that was it. I needed to rerun the server. Lesson well-learned. Cheers! And thanks for everyone else who took the time to check as well.

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug with ionic hot reload. I experience it with ionic 3. Make sure the method name is correct. If you still get the error:

- repeatedly save the .ts, .html etc files where you made recent changes. And hope the next reload works
- Refresh the browser
- If you are using device debugging on chrome, change the target device.
- The last but sure way to fix it is to run `ionic serve` again